# URI string variable declared in prolog returns error "not a sub-type of xs:anyURI"

Tags: xquery, exist-db

In Xquery 3.1 (eXist 4.7) I am using the `httpclient` [function](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/httpclient&location=java:org.exist.xquery.modules.httpclient.HTTPClientModule&details=true) to send `GET` requests:

```
httpclient:get($url as xs:anyURI, $persist as xs:boolean, $request-headers as 
element()?) as item()
```

My function looks like this:

```
declare function example:get()
{
   let $url := "https://api.example.org/groups/1234/items?format=atom&amp;content=tei&amp;v=3"              
   let $APIdoc := httpclient:get($url,true(),<headers/>)
   return $APIdoc
};
```

and it executes fine.

But if I declare the identical URI string in the prolog like this:

```
declare variable $example:API_URL := "https://api.example.org/groups/1234/items?format=atom&amp;content=tei&amp;v=3";

declare function example:get()
{
   let $APIdoc := httpclient:get($example:API_URL,true(),<headers/>)
   return $APIdoc
};
```

I receive the following error:

> err:XPTY0004 xs:string(https://api.example.org/groups/1234/itemsformat=atom&content=tei&v=3) is not a sub-type of xs:anyURI

Why would there be a difference between URI strings declared in the function and in the prolog?

How do I solve this so I can use a URI string variable declared in the prolog?

Comment: It may built in such a way that it doesn't automatically coerce into the desired type. Try explicitly casting your URL variable by wrapping it in `xs:anyURI()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any of these should succeed according to the W3C specs: you can use a URI where a string is expected, but not the other way around. The solution is simple: cast the string to a URI, by writing

```
httpclient:get(xs:anyURI($example:API_URL), ...)
```

Comment: `xs:anyURI` worked, thanks. My first function does indeed work (in eXist-db). And indeed if I pass the prolog string to another local variable first, I can then use it as well.